# Difference between root to and get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Between these two commands:

```
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  #get 'static_pages/home'
```

If I use the first one I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home.html"

Rails.root: /Users/Jony/RubymineProjects/sample_app
```

for accessing `http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home.html`

But if I use the second one, it just works fine.

What is the difference and how can I fix it to use the first style of routing?

Comment: When you use first form, you should navigate to `http://localhost:3000/` (that is, *root*).

Comment: Thanks, ah that was tricky, Worked now.

Answer (score 0):

`root_to`: is used to show the home page. i.e., page which is user landed into site.

To solve your problem:

First provide route to static_pages/home using

```
get "static_pages/home"
```

and then add

```
root to: "static_pages#home"
```